# How to avoid a delay with start playing audio file in Safari

Tags: audio, safari

Im using AWS CloudFront to deliver audio file (mp3) over the network. 
There is a delay in 7-10 seconds until the audio file start playing in Safari. No delay in Chrome. The file size is ~30MB.

How to avoid or minimize this delay. It affects on user experience significantly.

It looks like Safari loads full audio file.

Thank you for any idea.